# XSLT filter duplicates in result

Tags: xslt

I"m trying to figure out how to avoid duplicates in the result set
when applying XSLT transformation (I'm using XSLT 1.0)

Here's XML source:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="1.xsl"?>
<root>
<item>
<code>AA</code>
<included-code>XX</included-code>
<included-code>YY</included-code>
<included-code>WW</included-code>
</item>
<item>
<code>BB</code>
<included-code>ZZ</included-code>
<included-code>XX</included-code>
<included-code>YY</included-code>
</item>
<item>
<code>CC</code>
<included-code>VV</included-code>
<included-code>XX</included-code>
<included-code>WW</included-code>
</item>
</root>
```

Here's stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">

  <result>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </result>

</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="item">
    <new-item>
      <code><xsl:value-of select="code"/></code>
      <xsl:variable name="main_code"><xsl:value-of select="code"/></xsl:variable>
      <xsl:for-each select="included-code">
        <xsl:variable name="current_code"><xsl:value-of select="text()"/></xsl:variable>
        <included-code><xsl:value-of select="$current_code"/></included-code>
        <xsl:for-each select="/root/item[included-code=$current_code and code!=$main_code]">
          <included-code><xsl:value-of select="code"/></included-code>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </new-item>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here's the result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><result>
<new-item>
<code>AA</code>
<included-code>XX</included-code>
<included-code>BB</included-code>
<included-code>CC</included-code>
<included-code>YY</included-code>
<included-code>BB</included-code>
<included-code>WW</included-code>
<included-code>CC</included-code>
</new-item>
<new-item>
<code>BB</code>
<included-code>ZZ</included-code>
<included-code>XX</included-code>
<included-code>AA</included-code>
<included-code>CC</included-code>
<included-code>YY</included-code>
<included-code>AA</included-code>
</new-item>
<new-item>
<code>CC</code>
<included-code>VV</included-code>
<included-code>XX</included-code>
<included-code>AA</included-code>
<included-code>BB</included-code>
<included-code>WW</included-code>
<included-code>AA</included-code>
</new-item>
</result>
```

The question is - how to avoid  with duplicate values in the result. I.e. here's what expected:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><result>
<new-item>
<code>AA</code>
<included-code>XX</included-code>
<included-code>BB</included-code>
<included-code>CC</included-code>
<included-code>YY</included-code>
<included-code>WW</included-code>
</new-item>
<new-item>
<code>BB</code>
<included-code>ZZ</included-code>
<included-code>XX</included-code>
<included-code>AA</included-code>
<included-code>CC</included-code>
<included-code>YY</included-code>
</new-item>
<new-item>
<code>CC</code>
<included-code>VV</included-code>
<included-code>XX</included-code>
<included-code>AA</included-code>
<included-code>BB</included-code>
<included-code>WW</included-code>
</new-item>
</result>
```

---

Thanks LarsH! Looks like the following script does the trick:
(I'm relatively new to XSLT, so not sure if there's more elegant way to keep list of already outputted values)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">

  <result>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </result>

</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="item">
  <new-item>
    <code><xsl:value-of select="code"/></code>
    <xsl:variable name="main_code"><xsl:value-of select="code"/></xsl:variable>
    <xsl:call-template name="processIncludedCodes">
      <xsl:with-param name="main_code" select="./code"/>
      <xsl:with-param name="codes" select="./included-code"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
  </new-item>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="processIncludedCodes">
  <xsl:param name="main_code"/>
  <xsl:param name="codes"/>
  <xsl:param name="outputCodes"/>
  <xsl:if test="$codes">
    <xsl:variable name="current_code"><xsl:value-of select="$codes[1]"/></xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="outputCode" select="concat(':', $codes[1], ':')"/>
    <xsl:if test="not(contains($outputCodes, $outputCode))">
      <included-code><xsl:value-of select="$codes[1]"/></included-code>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:for-each select="/root/item[included-code=$current_code and code!=$main_code]">
      <xsl:if test="not(contains($outputCodes, ./code))">
        <included-code><xsl:value-of select="code"/></included-code>
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:variable name="outputCodes2">
      <xsl:for-each select="/root/item[included-code=$current_code and code!=$main_code]">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(':', code, ':')"/>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="newOutputCodes" select="concat($outputCodes, $outputCode, $outputCodes2)"/>
    <xsl:call-template name="processIncludedCodes">
      <xsl:with-param name="main_code" select="$main_code"/>
      <xsl:with-param name="codes" select="$codes[position() > 1]"/>
      <xsl:with-param name="outputCodes" select="$newOutputCodes"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Good q. This looks like the problem for which the usual answer is to process the input list recursively, passing a variable that accumulates a list of what has already been sent to output, so you can avoid outputting it again. There are a couple of examples at least on SO, but I'll let you search for them.

Comment: I think I understand what you mean. Thank you, I'll give it a try.

Comment: OK. Sorry for the terse answer... I'm on a deadline at work. Let us know as you have questions. Maybe @DimitreNovachev will post a full solution soon. :-)

Comment: Thanks again, LarsH! I posted updated script above. Please, let me know if I did it correctly the way you suggested.

Comment: @AndreiM: Can you, please, explain what the transformation is supposed to do? This isn't clear.

Comment: For each item, it is supposed to pick any current <included-code>'s, plus for any other item with an <included-code> in common with given item, it takes the <code> and puts it into <included-code> tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without any recursion:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/root">
        <root>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="item"/>
        </root>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="item">
        <new-item>
            <xsl:copy-of select="code"/>
            <xsl:for-each select="included-code | /root/item[included-code = current()/included-code]/code[. != current()/included-code and . != current()/code]">
                <included-code>
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </included-code>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </new-item>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It picks any current `<included-code>`'s, plus for any item with an `<included-code>` in common, it picks the `<code>`, if it has not already been included.

**Output:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
   <new-item>
      <code>AA</code>
      <included-code>XX</included-code>
      <included-code>YY</included-code>
      <included-code>WW</included-code>
      <included-code>BB</included-code>
      <included-code>CC</included-code>
   </new-item>
   <new-item>
      <code>BB</code>
      <included-code>AA</included-code>
      <included-code>ZZ</included-code>
      <included-code>XX</included-code>
      <included-code>YY</included-code>
      <included-code>CC</included-code>
   </new-item>
   <new-item>
      <code>CC</code>
      <included-code>AA</included-code>
      <included-code>BB</included-code>
      <included-code>VV</included-code>
      <included-code>XX</included-code>
      <included-code>WW</included-code>
   </new-item>
</root>
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much. Very elegant solution to this particular problem.

Comment: This probably deserves a +1, but I haven't had time to analyze the question well enough to determine the correctness of the answer. Unfortunately the question is not very explicit about the desired transformation.

Comment: @LarsH The question seems very abstract to me. I went by the original XSLT-ode, which just picked the `<code>` of any `<item>` that shared any `<included-code>`.